# Django rest authentication error: "Unable to log in with provided credentials."

Tags: django-rest-framework, token, django-authentication

i'm trying to create a based token user auth in django rest, but i always obtain the          "Unable to log in with provided credentials." error.
Here is the api views to perform login on an registered user already associated whith a token

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token

from rest_framework.authtoken.views import ObtainAuthToken
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from rest_framework.response import Response


class Login(ObtainAuthToken):

   def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       
       serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data, context={'request': request})
       serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
       user = serializer.validated_data['CustomUser']
       token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
       return Response({
           'token': token.key,
           'user_id': user.pk,
           'email': user.email
       })
```

Here is the user model

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, Group,Permission

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    projects = models.ManyToManyField('Project',related_name='shared_projects',blank=True)
    activity = models.ManyToManyField('Activity',related_name='present_in_activities',blank=True)
    groups = models.ManyToManyField('CustomGroup', related_name="user_group",blank=True)
    tasks = models.ManyToManyField('Task',related_name='assigned_task',blank=True)
    profile = models.OneToOneField('Profile',related_name='user_profile',on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,blank=True,null=True)
    user_permissions = models.ManyToManyField(
        Permission,
        verbose_name='user permissions',
        blank=True,
        related_name='user_custom_permissions'
    )
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

when i do a post request, i obtain this response:

```
{
    "non_field_errors": [
        "Unable to log in with provided credentials."
    ]
}
```

but user credential are ok, i check them in django admin.

Here is the registration serializer

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from myapp.models import CustomUser
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token

class SignUp(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['username','password']
    
    def validate_username(self,username):
        
        if CustomUser.objects.filter(username = username).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError('Username gia esistente')
        return username
            
    def create(self,validated_data):
        user = CustomUser(
            username = validated_data['username'],
            password = validated_data['password']
        )        
        try:
            user.save()
            Token.objects.create(user = user)
            return user
        except:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('Ops qualcosa è andato storto')
```

can someone explain me why i have this kind of error ?
Than you so much